# How to get array object in nested array of array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, javascript-objects

I would like to know how to get the array object in nested array object using javascript.
Below is the object `obj`, should get the obj with the children1 status having `Active` and `Updated`.

```
var obj = [{
   "id": 1,
   "status":"updated",
   "code": "product",
   "children": [
     {
        "id" : 20,
      "title": "cafe",
      "children1": [
        {"id": "2", "title": "SG", "status": "Active"},
        {"id": "3", "title": "TH", "status": "Updated"},
        {"id": "4", "title": "MY", "status": "Deleted"}
      ]
     },
     {
        "id" : 21,
      "title": "others",
      "children1": [
        {"id": "5", "title": "tours", "status": "Active"},
        {"id": "6", "title": "services", "status": "Updated"},
        {"id": "7", "title": "finance", "status": "Deleted"}
      ]
     }
   ]
}]


function getActiveUpdtedObj (obj){
  var result = obj.filter(e=>e.children.filter(i=>i.children1.status !=="Deleted"));
  console.log(result);
}

this.getActiveUpdtedObj(obj);
```

Expected Result

```
[{
   "id": 1,
   "status":"updated",
   "code": "product",
   "children": [
     {
        "id" : 20,
      "title": "cafe",
      "children1": [
        {"id": "2", "title": "SG", "status": "Active"},
        {"id": "3", "title": "TH", "status": "Updated"}
      ]
     },
     {
        "id" : 21,
      "title": "others",
      "children1": [
        {"id": "5", "title": "tours", "status": "Active"},
        {"id": "6", "title": "services", "status": "Updated"}
      ]
     }
   ]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

So first you iterate over `obj` array (it is an array, not an object), with `.map`, and return the same current object (using the spread operator `{...o}`), and overriding children property with newly filtered `children` array.

Now, how to get this newly filtered `children` array?

Perform another iteration with `.map` on `.children` property of your current object, access each of `child`'s `children1` property and filter it. Construct and return new child object (again with the spread operator) by overriding its `children1` property with newly filtered array. Done, now you have new top-level `children` array.

```
obj.map(o => {
  const newChildren = o.children.map(child => {
    const newChildren1 = child.children1.filter(c => c.status !== 'Deleted');
    return { ...child, children1: newChildren1 };
  });

  return { ...o, children: newChildren }
});
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what it does and how it helps.

Answer (score 0):

One possible method is the following :

```
function getActiveUpdtedObj(obj) {
  var result = obj.map(e => {
    e.children = e.children.map(child => {
      child.children1 = child.children1.filter(c => c['status'] !== "Deleted");
      return child
    });
    return e
  });
}
```

at the very top level, you might want to do `map` on the object itself (meaning transform each element), then for each element you want to edit only its `children.children1` data. At this point, you will need `filter`.

**Notes:**

- you can do `reduce` as well but that will be a bit more complicate ;D
- you can checkout `lodash` library, it's so good for collection manipulation https://lodash.com/docs

Answer (score 0):

You can mutate the original object like:

```js
var obj = [
  {
    id: 1,
    status: 'updated',
    code: 'product',
    children: [
      {
        id: 20,
        title: 'cafe',
        children1: [
          { id: '2', title: 'SG', status: 'Active' },
          { id: '3', title: 'TH', status: 'Updated' },
          { id: '4', title: 'MY', status: 'Deleted' },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 21,
        title: 'others',
        children1: [
          { id: '5', title: 'tours', status: 'Active' },
          { id: '6', title: 'services', status: 'Updated' },
          { id: '7', title: 'finance', status: 'Deleted' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

for (const { children } of obj) {
  for (const child of children) {
    child.children1 = child.children1.filter(e => e.status !== 'Deleted');
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map`, `filter` and rest operator to get the desired result:

```
const result = arr.map(({children, ...rest}) => ({...rest, 
  children: children.map(({children1, ...rest1 }) => ({ ...rest1, 
      children1: children1.filter(f => f.status == 'Active' 
          || f.status == 'Updated') }))}))
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [{
   "id": 1,
   "status": "updated",
   "code": "product",
   "children": [
      {
         "id": 20,
         "title": "cafe",
         "children1": [
            { "id": "2", "title": "SG", "status": "Active" },
            { "id": "3", "title": "TH", "status": "Updated" },
            { "id": "4", "title": "MY", "status": "Deleted" }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id": 21,
         "title": "others",
         "children1": [
            { "id": "5", "title": "tours", "status": "Active" },
            { "id": "6", "title": "services", "status": "Updated" },
            { "id": "7", "title": "finance", "status": "Deleted" }
         ]
      }
   ]
}]

const result = arr.map(({children, ...rest}) => ({...rest, children: children.map(({children1, ...rest1 }) =>
   ({ ...rest1, children1: children1.filter(f => f.status == 'Active' || f.status == 'Updated') }))}))
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better method would be using array methods map() and filter() as in this code

```
function getActiveUpdtedObj (obj){
  var result = obj.map(object => ({
    ...object,
    children: object.children.map(child => ({
       ...child,
       children1: child.children1.filter(child1 => child1.status !== 'Deleted')
    }))
  }));
  console.log(result);
}
```

Let know if the answer helped.